# Forçar path fixo no Nextjs

Tags: javascript, react, path, next.js

Estou com um projeto Nextjs que precisa rodar com um path como por exemplo:

localhost:3000/nomedoprojeto

Fiz essa configuração no arquivo next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/nomedoprojeto',
}
```

a aplicação rodou assim, porem nos links do do menu eles apontam para a baseUrl que no caso é : localhost:3000/ fazendo assim com q a pagina nao seja encontrada.
se eu colocar a url direto no navegador funciona.
Gostaria de forçar ele a sempre que chegar alguma requisição para a '/' ele adicione automaticamente '/nomedoprojeto/'

Answer (score -1):

vc pode usar o getServerSideProps ou o getInitialProps do Next.js.

COM getServerSideProps:

```
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req, res } = context;

  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/nomedoprojeto' });
    res.end();
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

COM getInitialProps:

```
function HomePage() {
  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
}

HomePage.getInitialProps = ({ res, pathname }) => {
  if (pathname === '/') {
    res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/nomedoprojeto' });
    res.end();
  }

  return {};
};

export default HomePage;
```

Isso só funciona para o servidor. Nao dará certo quando a aplicação tiver em produção. Se tiver em produção, tem que configurar o servidor web que estiver sendo usado (como o Nginx) para fazer o redirecionamento

Comment: Nesse caso eu vou precisar mudar todos os lugares q chamam essas rotas? Não dá pra colocar em um arquivo só alguma configuração que faça a reescrita da rota?

Comment: Se vc tá usando Next.js para criar uma aplicação, a maneira recomendada de redirecionar uma rota é usando o método getServerSideProps() ou getInitialProps(). 
Mas se quiser centralizar o redirecionamento em um único arquivo, pode criar um componente que use o método getServerSideProps() ou getInitialProps() e, em seguida, importar esse componente em todas as páginas que precisam de redirecionamento
Vc poderia criar um componente chamado Redirect.js que contém a lógica de redirecionamento e exportá-lo para ser importado em suas páginas